# How to install all packages from current local directory with pip3 in powershell

Tags: powershell, pip

I would expect:

```
pip3 install ./*
```

or possibly

```
pip3 install ./*.whl
```

but neither of these work. I get:

```
ERROR: Invalid requirement: './*'
```

I'm trying to install torch, torchvision and torchaudio having already fetched all the necessary packages to a local folder.

I can run the specific .whl for torch, but then it goes and downloads the dependencies again, even though they're already in the current directory.

Comment: I am not familiar with Powershell, so there might be a limitation there that I do not know of, but in principle from *pip*'s side this should work. I am quite sure it does work in bash on Linux. -- Anyway, you should edit your question to copy-paste the results of the command including error messages if any. -- Maybe what you are missing are the `--no-index` and `--no-deps` options: `python -m pip install --no-index --no-deps ./*.whl`.

Comment: Related docs: [PowerShell about_Wildcards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_wildcards?view=powershell-7.3)

Comment: Shouldn't it be `pip3 install .\*.whl` ?

Comment: I don't have pip, but a simple `ls ./.ssh` in my root folder does what it looks like it will do.  @phd `ls .\.ssh` does the same thing.  PS is expanding the . to 'current working directory' and uses / as \.  Also `ls` and `gci` are aliases for `get-childitem`.  So the problem must be that pip3 is preventing expansion of the path.

Answer (score -2):

I can't specifically say why the syntax ./* didn't work, but I can report what worked for me:

instead of attempting to run the .whl installers directly, I simply ran the install command for the package from the folder where the packages reside:

```
pip3 install torch torchaudio torchvision
```

powershell used the "cached" files to run the installation.

Comment: FWIW, the `.whl` files in the working directory never entered the picture when you ran that command. The "cache files" are from pip's own internal cache from having previously downloaded those packages. PowerShell is also completely uninvolved in the installation process.

Comment: Indeed, this does not install the wheel files from you own directory. I do not see the point of this answer in relation to the question.

Comment: This is not the right answer.  This is a hard coded workaround.